# ggplot - dual line chart and stacked bar chart on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data consists of a date variable and four numeric variables, of the 4 numeric variables I wish to plot two of these as a stacked bar chart and the remaining variables as line charts.

Is it possible to create two line charts and a stacked bar chart in a single plot using ggplot?

My data looks as follows:

```
data <- tibble(Month = 1:12,Brands = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),Generics = Brands + 1,Metric1 = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,10),Metric2 = c(10,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))
```

I wish to plot months on the x axis, Brands1 & Brands2 as stacked bar charts and Metric1 & Metric2 as line charts all on the same chart if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(Month = 1:12,Brands = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),Generics = Brands + 1,Metric1 = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,10),Metric2 = c(10,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Brands,Generics)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Metric1,Metric2),
               names_to = "metric_name",values_to = "metric_value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Month))+
  geom_col(aes(y = value, fill = name))+
  geom_line(aes(y = metric_value, col = metric_name),size = 1.25)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","purple"))
```

Comment: Felix this is great thank you very much. If the line and bars were on two very different scales is it possible to add a second axis?

Comment: This is a "complicated" topic in ggplot2, here is a reference: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html